# Prevent iframe from loading on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mobile

I am working on my portfolio page and I want to have my projects in a demo mode where the user can preview the sites in different viewports. I got the idea from here:
http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis/#demo-full

On mobile devices I would like to keep the iframes from loading, and instead have links to the projects open the sites in the new tab.

If I have the divs containing the iframes hidden at the very top of my CSS file with display:none, I can see the iframes still load in the background and the page takes a long time to load.

Is there any way to keep them from loading at all when on a certain device or viewport size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could achieve this by using JavaScript and the HTML Data-Attribut. By setting the src-Attribute to something like "#" it won't load anything. You can use the data-Attribute to store the URL for use with JavaScript.

```
<iframe src="#" data-src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Then you just check to screen size with window.matchMedia() and set the src-attribute at a specific screen size.

```
var $iframe = $('iframe'),
    src = $iframe.data('src');

if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)").matches) {
    $iframe.attr('src', src);
}
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5LnjL3uc/

If you want to show the iframe after a user resizes the window you need to put your code into a function and bind it to a resize event:

```
var $iframe = $('iframe'),
    src = $iframe.data('src');

function showIframe() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)").matches) {
        $iframe.attr('src', src);
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', showIframe);

// Initialize it once on document ready
showIframe();
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5LnjL3uc/1/

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I'm a little confused though. First, I'm using the One Page Scroll plugin. When a button is clicked, I use JS to show a hidden demo frame which contains the iframe. For whatever reason, having a "#" makes it just jump to the top page. So leaving "" empty works. But the iframe no longer loads no matter what the screen size. And in your jfiddle, the cat is always there.

Comment: To see the smaller version (hidden iFrame) in the fiddle you need to resize the box with the cat pic and hit the run button in the top menu.

Comment: Could you figure it out or do you need more help on the matter?

Comment: Actually, I am still having issues. I just can't figure it out! If I can't soon, I may have to change the design.

I don't want the iframe to load at all under a certain width. I plan on also hiding the buttons that are there now with a slider. 

This is the website http://portfolio.cairndigitalmedia.com/

I would like to have the iframes load AFTER the page loads as well. I have tried a few methods but it seems to interfere with One Page Scroll. Not sure if it's a browser memory issue or what. But if the iframes load after the page, it just doesn't work well.

Comment: What modification do I make for multiple iframes?  At the moment this updates all of them to the same src.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to approach this in reverse.

IE do not load the src to begin with by placing your URL in a attribute like 'data-src' for example.

See my code for this below. You simply copy the data-src to your src when your device, or device width is not mobile/mobile size.

I believe this is the best solution because there are no uncertainties. With the previously mentioned solutions (which I tried) you are racing against the clock with the browser for when your code runs and it decides to load the iframe src.

```
if(device !== true) {
  // add '#' to the href
  let iframe = document.getElementById('3dExperience')
  iframe.src = iframe.getAttribute('data-src')
}
```

Note: 'device' is the [is-mobile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-mobile) npm package for detecting mobile.